# Is it possible to evaluate a list of functions within a for-loop where the iterator is the argument?

Tags: python, exception, iterator, sage

I'm working on a Python function which determines whether or not a number is [stealthy](https://projecteuler.net/problem=757). I'm using Sagemath for various tests.

While I can easily write a code which checks the... anti-criteria... of a given number, it makes more sense to have an ordered list of functions that take an argument.

The linked problem wants me to check how many stealthy numbers are less than 10^14. It's elementary to say that any prime number is decidedly not stealthy (as all prime numbers are only divisible by themselves and one and cannot be both even and odd). However, there are other things which may disqualify a number (the parity of a number doesn't obviously imply stealthiness).

Let's say I have a list:

```
fail_list = ["is_prime({})", "is_prime_power({})",...]
```

and I want to pass some iterator as the argument. For some of the functions, it's faster to disqualify a number with a less expensive computation and there are potentially number theoretic reasons to do so (say, for a large number, it's faster to find the number of divisors as opposed to checking for primality, etc.).

In essence, using the list above, I want to be able to evaluate some iterator `N` and break if the test passes.

```
for N in range(1, rng+1):
    for test in fail_list.format(N):
        try:
            if test():
                print("Not Stealthy")
                break
            else:
                print("Stealthy")
                stealth_count += 1
                break
        except:
            Exception
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: In your sample code, `N` is an integer, not an iterator. The test functions take an integer argument, right?  Why don't you make `fail_list = [is_prime, is_prime_power,...]`a list of functions (no need for strings), and just call `for test in fail_list: ... if test(N):`?  Also, your `else` clause shouldn't `break`, since it's only stealthy if all the fail tests return `false`, not just the first.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Now onto writing some lambda functions for the more obscure disqualifiers...

Comment: This is also a good time to learn about `all` and `any`.  `if any(test(n) for test in fail_list):...`